# Sample size vs. number of samples

Tags: sampling

This question came up in an archaeology class, and it seems like it should be something very basic.

Suppose I want to count the number of marbles in a large bucket of sediment. I only have the manpower to process 20 liters of sediment in total.

Is it better to take:
20 samples of 1 liter each
5 samples of 4 liters each
1 sample of 20 liters
...?

Does it even matter, if the same total amount of sediment ends up being counted?

I am assuming that that this is with replacement, so the sediment in a sample is tossed back in after its marbles are counted.

Comment: I don't see how the sediments are important here. Aren't you counting the marbles? Are you tossing the marbles back?

Comment: Yes, you take out some amount of the material. Count the marbles in it, then toss everything back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking a question about the potential value of *stratified sampling*. Stratified sampling only makes sense when your population is naturally differentiated into different classes (e.g., brown vs. grey sediment), and you have some reason to believe that this difference may have an effect on the data-generating process (e.g., that brown sediment may be more marble-rich than grey sediment).

Whether or not your results are sensitive to how you stratify your sample depends entirely on whether there is *heterogeneity* in the true distribution depending on some observable differentiating characteristic.

It sounds in your case as if there is no such differentiating characteristic: sediment is sediment is sediment. In that case, the choice of stratification program will not affect your results.

Comment: I wish that sediment were like this! Instead, unless it is purposely well mixed, it tends to be well stratified and heterogeneous. How it is sampled can make a *tremendous* difference.  (Think about it: a fundamental archeological technique is to use vertical position within sedimentary strata to data artifacts: that alone shows that sediment cannot validly be considered a homogeneous medium for archeological purposes.)

Comment: So: is the question about marbles, or bones?

Comment: It's about "sediment," as I recall. About the only good reason I can think of to contemplate the different sampling procedures listed in the question is because one is concerned about the heterogeneity of the medium. In stating "sediment is sediment," your answer appears to dismiss that possibility out of hand. My comment suggests that is missing the point--whether or not one is doing archeology and whether or not one is sampling actual marbles or using marbles and sediment as metaphors for some other sampling situation.

Comment: Then, in general, in a non stratified problem, does the number of samples matter or only the size of each sample?